# Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable

Tags: php, laravel

I have the controllers below to allow the user login with laravel auth system but also to login with facebook using socialite.

But when the user clicks in the button "Login with facebook" it appears this error:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, string given, called in AuthManager.php on line 292.
```

The user is stored in the database but that error appears. Do you know why?

Do you know why?

```
class OauthController extends Controller
{

    public function redirectToProvider($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();

    }


    public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {
        $userFace = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
        // $user->token;

        $findUser = User::where('email', $userFace->email)->first();

        if($findUser){
            Auth::login($findUser);
        }else{
            $user = new User;
            $user->name = $userFace->name;
            $user->surname = "";
            $user->email = $userFace->email;
            $user->password = bcrypt($user->name);
            $user->save();
            Auth::login($userFace->email);
        }
    }
}
```

AuthController:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login(){


        if(\Input::has('code')){

        }


        return \Socialite::with('facebook')->redirect();
    }
}
```

LoginController:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        if(Route::getRoutes()->match(Request::create(\URL::previous()))->getName() == "cong.reg") {
            return (Request::create(\URL::previous())->getRequestUri());
        }
        return $this->redirectTo;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$user = new User;
$user->name = $userFace->name;
$user->surname = "";
$user->email = $userFace->email;
$user->password = bcrypt($user->name);
$user->save();
Auth::login($userFace);
```

Comment: Thanks, but same issue.

Comment: You have this line in User.php? class User extends Authenticatable

Comment: oh, try Auth::login($user); in this code. you should pass user object in Auth::login

Comment: Thanks but same error with "            Auth::login($userFace);
".

Comment: you write $user = new User;
$user->name = $userFace->name;
$user->surname = "";
$user->email = $userFace->email;
$user->password = bcrypt($user->name);
$user->save(); Auth::login($user)?

Comment: Thanks, now the error dont appears. But when the user clicks in "Login with facebook" is redirected to the facebook page and it appears a blank page, do you know why?

Comment: It appears the blank page and the user is not redirected back to the "http://proj.test/".

Comment: check facebook settings in config/services.php

Comment: Thanks, it seems correct, the redirect is like:  'redirect' => 'http://proj.test/auth/facebook/callback'

Comment: its local site or in th internet? facebook not see your local domains

Comment: its local, so its normal appear a blank page and not redirect to the local site?

Answer (score -1):

class AuthController extends Controller
{

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();

}


public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    $userFace = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
    // $user->token;
```

correct spellings of AuthController and use it.

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)?