# Socialite : Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given

Tags: php, laravel

I made a socialite login using Google and Facebook, but in the SocialiteController section there is an error like the question above.

this is my SocialiteController

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use App\SocialAccount;
use App\User;

class SocialiteController extends Controller
{
    public function redirectToProvider($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);
        Auth::login($authUser, true);
        return redirect('/personal');
    }

    public function findOrCreateUser($socialUser, $provider)
    {
        $socialAccount = SocialAccount::where('provider_id', $socialUser->getId())
                        ->where('provider_name', $provider)
                        ->first();

        if($socialAccount) {
            return $socialAccount->user;
        } else {
            $user = User::where('email', $socialUser->getEmail())->first();
            if(!$user) {
                $user = User::create([
                    'username' => $socialUser->getName(),
                    'email' => $socialUser->getEmail()

                ]);
                $user->assignRole('Registered');
            }

            $user->socialAccounts()->create([
                'provider_id' => $socialUser->getId(),
                'provider_name' => $provider
            ]);

            return $user;
        }
    }
}
```

this is my User model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use App\Profile;
use App\Article;
use App\Video;
use App\Images;
use App\News;

class User extends Authenticatable Implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable, HasRoles;
    protected $table = "users";
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password'
    ];


    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }

    public function article()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
    }

    public function socialAccounts()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(SocialAccount::class);
    }

    public function video(){
        return $this->hasMany(Video::class);
    }

    public function news(){
        return $this->hasMany(News::class);
    }
}
```

the complete error message like this : 
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in /home/asyj6686/public_html/sublaravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php on line 297

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50544857/type-error-argument-1-passed-to-illuminate-auth-sessionguardlogin-must-impl)

Comment: I've tried it but it's still an error

Comment: my error is "null given", but in that question error is "string given"

Answer (score 2):

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given

This error is pretty straight-forward. It means that you have passed a `null` value to the login.

```php
Auth::login($authUser, true);
```

I don't see anything wrong with the provided code. Therefore, I'm going to guess that you may have simply forgotten to add the inverse relationship with *User* in the *SocialAccount* model. This would cause `$socialAccount->user` to return `null` and generate the error you are receiving.

**App\SocialAccount.php**

```php
class SocialAccount extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

On a side note, shouldn't a *User* be able to `->hasMany()` *SocialAccount*s?